# Cannot get JQueryMobile CSS/JS to load in PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to set up a basic example using PhoneGap and JQuery mobile. I cannot get the page to load properly in my browser. The problem is the page is just rendering like normal html.

Sources I've consulted..
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android_2_install_sdk_cordova
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

It should look like this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-template.html

What I'm getting:
[image]

My folder structure:

```
/assets/  
-/www/  
--/cordova-2.4.0.js  
--/index.html  
--/jquery-1.8.2.js  
--/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css  
--/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js
```

Here's my basic html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PhoneGap</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css"/>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <body> 

        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Single page</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">   
                <p>This is a single page boilerplate template that you can copy to build your first jQuery Mobile page. Each link or form from here will pull a new page in via Ajax to support the animated page transitions.</p>      
                <p>Just view the source and copy the code to get started. All the CSS and JS is linked to the jQuery CDN versions so this is super easy to set up. Remember to include a meta viewport tag in the head to set the zoom level.</p>
                <p>This template is standard HTML document with a single "page" container inside, unlike a <a href="multipage-template.html" data-ajax="false">multi-page template</a> that has multiple pages within it. We strongly recommend building your site or app as a series of separate pages like this because it's cleaner, more lightweight and works better without JavaScript.</p>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <button>text</button>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Footer content</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->

        </div><!-- /page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Here's what's in my logcat..

```
02-20 11:31:47.342: E/Web Console(18138): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js:2655
```

Here's a link to google drive with my www folder in it...
https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B3ALaz5FfLwgZUJjdW1PTnJyblE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try using JQuery Mobile CDN-hosted. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I wouldn't do that ... your JS assets need to be locally-sourced for a mobile phone, or you run the risk of them not being able to be loaded after the project is compiled and installed.

Comment: I see you have a reference to jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js but the structure you listed just says jquery.mobile.js ... have you double checked to make sure that the files are being loaded with the correct names? You can look in Firebug or Chrome's Developer tools to check for any 404's for those assets. I'd check there, first, and make sure that all the files that you're trying to load are being loaded by the page.

Comment: That was my mistake.. It's actually jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js in the file structure.

Comment: If I add the links CDN-Hosted it loads fine, but like mori57 said, that's not a good way to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in **jquery-1.9.1.js** , jQuery Mobile 1.2 is not going to work with any jQuery above version 1.8.3.

You can even test it on this jSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/yWTG2/, you only need to change jQuery version in top left corner. Change it to a 1.9.1. and everything will brake.

So change this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

to a version 1.8.3.

**EDIT :**

I have downloaded your source. I found that your jQuery Mobile css and js source are the problem, redownload them from my jsFiddle example. Then everything will work correctly.

Comment: The docs themselves agree: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/ "For jQuery 1.7.0 to 1.8.2."

Comment: Just tried updating it to version 1.8.2 and that did not work :\

Edit: I updated my OP to match my current code/folder structure.

Comment: something is wrong with your jQuery Mobile css and js file. Redownload them again, use my jsFiddle example as a source. Everything works with new files, and jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: It was something wrong with the files.. I don't know what though :\